# Are signal handlers meant to run indefinitely?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, signals

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

void handler(int signo){
    std::cout << "Caught " << (signo == SIGINT) << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    while(true) ;

}
```

On Windows and Linux these seem to do two different things when I press <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *multiple* times. On Linux I will see the caught message multiple times, whereas on Windows I will see the caught message once, and on the second press of <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> my program will close. So are the handlers meant to catch the signal only once, or indefinitely? Or is there a property of Windows I am missing that is causing the program to close on second press?

[As far as I can tell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541(v=vs.85).aspx) <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is treated as SIGINT on Windows just like it is on Linux.

Comment: Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx

Comment: @latedeveloper Thanks, I was looking at the cppreference.com documentation which didn't mention it. Relevant line: "_Before the specified function is executed, the value of func is set to SIG_DFL_"

Comment: Note also that on Windows, the SIGINT handler is run in a separate thread.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Does that imply there would be no need to worry about "safe" functions to use in signal handlers on Windows, like you have to for Linux? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: @SergeantPenguin: only for SIGINT, and I'm not sure whether all C runtime library functions are thread-safe or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of `signal`, which might be equivalent to `sigaction` with the `SA_RESETHAND` flag set or clear -- either is acceptable accoding to the POSIX and C standards.

If you want to control this behavior, you need to use `sigaction` instead of `signal` to set up the signal handler and set the flags to get the desired behavior.

Comment: In addition, it's not safe to use std::cout in a posix signal handler. There is a list of safe functions here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html